# Trocar o texto do botão através do click

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como posso trocar o texto do botão toda vez que clicar no mesmo, como se fosse um *list-group* quando clica ele abre e fecha, eu fiz esse código:

```
function trocarFlecha()
{
  var x = document.getElementById('btnImage').value;
  if (x = "Imagem  &#709;") {
    document.getElementById('btnImage').innerHTML = "Imagem  &#706;"; 
  } else {
    document.getElementById('btnImage').innerHTML = "Imagem  &#709;";
  }
}
```

E adicionei um `onclick="trocarFlecha()"` no botão e ele troca apenas uma vez mas eu queria fazer de forma dinâmica, fazendo que toda vez que clique ele altere.

Comment: E qual é o texto que deveria ser exibido no segundo clique?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss No segundo clique ele voltaria ao texto original, por exemplo se o botão é igual a Imagem e quando clicado ele virá Vídeo, ao clicar de novo no mesmo botão ele vira Imagem novamente

Comment: No seu `if`, deveria ser `x == ...`, não apenas `x = ...`.

Comment: Fiz a troca mas acabou não funcionando nem no primeiro click

Answer (score -2):

Troque o `=` por `===` em:

```
if (x = "Imagem &#709;") {
    ....
}
```

EDIT: faça assim,

```
var cliquei = false;
function trocarFlecha()
{
  var x = document.getElementById('btnImage').value;
  if (cliquei = !cliquei) {
    document.getElementById('btnImage').value = "Imagem  &#706;"; 
  } else {
    document.getElementById('btnImage').value = "Imagem  &#709;";
  }
}
```

Comment: Fiz a troca mas acabou não funcionando nem no primeiro click

Comment: Tem dois espaços mesmo entre `Imagem` e `&#709;`?

Comment: Sim, é pra não muito ficar junto

Comment: Editei minha proposta de solução.

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado :D

Comment: Editei de novo a proposta de solução.